# Run Laravel Dusk on Cloudways

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk, cloudways

I'm running Laravel Dusk locally and everything is working.
When I want to run the tests on my Cloudways server I get the error message:

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\WebDriverCurlException: Curl error thrown for http POST to /session with params: {"desiredCapabilities":{"browserName":"chrome","platform":"ANY","chromeOptions":{"w3c":false,"binary":"","args":["--disable-gpu","--headless","--window-size=1920,1080"]}}}

Failed to connect to localhost port 9515: Connection refused
```

Unfortunately the great Cloudways support couldn't help. 
I'm setting the correct `APP_URL` in the .env.dusk and .env.dusk.local files - but nothing helped.

I'm wondering if anyone had the same problem or could help solve this one.

Comment: Which versions of PHP, Laravel and Dusk you are using on Cloudways?

Comment: Please see how dusk is setup on Cloudways: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/laravel-dusk-testing-todo-app/

Comment: I saw this article already and it shows how you can run DUSK locally - that is working fine for me, but I want to run the tests on the cloudway servers.

@ShahrozeNawaz I'm running PHP 7.3 on cloudways

Comment: Hi Konard, I talk to the dev team and the feedback is you can't install chromium driver on Cloudways server at this time. It needs a root access so can't be possible.